# Chrome Application JSON data open file

Tags: javascript, json, file, google-chrome-app

I want to create a Chrome Application. If I put a JSON file in the same folder how do I access the file? I want to find the correct way of getting the text into a variable, something like the example I found:

```
var json = $.getJSON("data.json");
```

I could not find in this example where the `$` object is defined. It must be some class. How can I use this in a Chrome Application?

Comment: The `$` is from the jQuery library, you need to add it to your aplication

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I still cannot load local data into a Chrome App so I have decided to try getting it in via Google Docs not really what I want but after wasting days I need to find another way. Once it's in I can use the local storage and API filesystem. I am just seeing if I could do things in a Chrome App that I can easily do in a Windows app if I can it opens so many possibilities.

Comment: I made a simple http server and collected the data from localhost. In the end I would need a server for updates later on anyway so this will be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it works the exact same way as if it was cross-origin:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(JSON.parse(this.response));
};
xhr.open('GET', '/data.json', true);
xhr.send();
```

Read more at [https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#cross-origin)

---

For those who are developing a Chrome Extension, you need to do it a little different according to this site: [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#extension-origin) (I haven't tested this.);

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(JSON.parse(this.response));
};
xhr.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('/data.json'), true);
xhr.send();
```

## Edit

If you want to use jQuery (as in the example that you found.):

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```